# Monoids in a Barr-exact category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a fast way to prove/disprove that the category of internal monoids in a Barr-exact category is itself Barr-exact? Direct computation seems sooo boring...

Comment: Perhaps you will get answers when you provide more background. Which sources have you already consulted? What's up with the special case of pointed sets? Etc.

Comment: Have you tried the internal logic?

Comment: @Martin: you're right, sorry. I couldn't find much informations about the claim in the OP, so I tried to prove that statement on my own. Let C be Barr-exact; Mon(C) inherits completeness of C, and if I'm not wrong any internal-monoid can be factored into $m\circ e$, with $m$ a mono, $e$ a regular (hence extremal) epimorphism. Here I stopped, but trying to examine a special case seems a good idea... it sounded so natural to me that I wanted to obtain it once and for all in full generality.
@Mike Shulman: your guess sounds good too. Unfortunately I'm not really keen on internal-manipulations..

Comment: Internal logic makes a lot of things easier... it might be worth your while to become keen on it.  (-:

Comment: :) @Mike: any clue to begin?

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic maybe, which contains some references.